# Postgres: partial unique index

Tags: postgresql

I want to protect the integrity of a state machine with a partial unique index. For a given `listing_id`, there should not be more than one record with `status < 3`.

In other words, this is ok:

```
listing_id, array_agg(status)
1234, {0,3,3}
```

But this is not:

```
listing_id, array_agg(status)
1234, {0,1,3}
```

My first thought was something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  uq_state_machine_protection_per_listing_id
  ON listing_version(listing_id, status)
  WHERE status in (0,1,2);
```

But that's not good enough-- it only prevents multiple records with the *same* value of less than 3. My negative case example above would still pass the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be dealt with by creating an index on constant. How about:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  uq_state_machine_protection_per_listing_id
  ON listing_version(listing_id)
  WHERE status in (0,1,2);
```

Comment: @kelorek Well, if you're including listing_id you don't need the other column.